# Symfony: Query without Entity

Tags: symfony, entitymanager

I'm looking for solution to use query by **entityManager** but without Entity (because for some reason, the table i want to connect with is have the column i want to call, but the entity don't have that column)

Something like this:

```
$getAddressIdByCheckoutIdQuery = $this->em->createQuery("
                SELECT c.shipping_address_id
                FROM Oro\Bundle\CheckoutBundle\Entity\Checkout c 
                WHERE c.id='" . $checkoutId . "'"
            );
```

But in entity doesn't have the **shipping_address_id**, so it give me an error:

> Class Oro\Bundle\CheckoutBundle\Entity\Checkout has no field or
>   association named shipping_address_id"

Please help, thanks.
And does it have any other options to query to database except **entityManager**? thanks for reading.

EDIT 1:

I've follow the `$em->getConnection()->prepareStatement($sql)`, and its return error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "prepareStatement" of
>   class "OroDoctrineConnection\ConnectionProxy

Here is how i did:

```
$getAddressIdByCheckoutIdQuery = $this->em->getConnection()->prepareStatement("
                    SELECT c.shipping_address_id
                    FROM oro_checkout c 
                    WHERE c.id='" . $checkoutId . "'"
                );

$getAddress = $getAddressIdByCheckoutIdQuery->getResult();
```

Comment: You need to use $em->getConnection()->prepareStatement($sql) for that. The raw dbal connection works like PDO.

Comment: so instead of $em->createQuery($sql), we use $em->getConnection()->prepareStatement($sql) ?

Comment: remember: In entity manager use php colum names, in raw sql use sql colum names.

Comment: Also replace any entities with their table names equivalent (from)

Comment: Might be better to [start with the docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#data-retrieval-and-manipulation).  The connection object is just pure sql.  So forget anything you learned about entity manager queries.  It will just confuse things.

Comment: Wow, nice, thanks you guys for helping me, i got this :3

Comment: Hello, the log said `Attempted to call an undefined method named "prepareStatement" of class "OroDoctrineConnection\ConnectionProxy`, what did i get wrong?

Comment: I've updated the post if you want to see how i did.

Comment: @Cerad may i know how to use this pure sql? i saw they call `$conn = DriverManager::getConnection($params, $config);`, i think we can't do that directly here.

Comment: Maybe fetch the connection from service container instead? I dont know OroCRM sorry